# Обновление бд mysql Теория и практика

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Обновляю БД mysql:

```
// 1. читается 1 запись из определенного файлика, в котором записи новые
// 2. идет 1 запрос к существующей бд - на основании этого идет анализ записи, и уже после анализа INSERT или UPDATE
// Итог: для импорта 1 записи - 3 запроса (опечатался, было написано 2)
```

В теории все просто, файлик, осуществляющий импорт - делает эту операцию пока записи для обновления не кончатся. Код писать (более менее) сам умею, спасибо всем **Гуру с Хэшкода**, что учили. Вот интересует на практике как делается то же обновление данных? Может чего то я не описал, и этого не знаю? (Интересует так же и производительность)

p.s. приведу аналогию по кулинарной книге:

```
//теория: ...берем эту субстанцию, засовываем в духовку на 40 минут. Потом высовываем и радуемся.
//практика: перед тем как высунуть нужно надеть варежку что бы не обжечься, да и газу всегда можно прибавить, и время сэкономить
```

Comment: Не пойму сути. Что за "файлик"? Что за "записи"? Как вы собираетесь их "анализировать" в БД? Если в каждой строке какое-нибудь предложение, то как вы проверять будете на существование данной записи в БД? Через LIKE %$str%? А если предложение будет отличаться всего лишь наличием точки в конце? В общем, можно еще много "если" придумать.

Comment: ух ты... в место 3х 1? не 2? можете пример привести такого запроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да пожалуйста) Вот читайте [insert-on-duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) )

```
INSERT INTO table (id,value) VALUES (1,2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);
```

Comment: очень полезная штука.